# What does this preprocessor line mean?

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

I am working on a project with the library ADOL-C (for automatic differentiation) using gcc. Right now I am trying to recompile the library to use the parallelization features however the make process does not working apparently due to some preprocessor stuff.

I think the problematic line is :

```
#define ADOLC_OPENMP_THREAD_NUMBER int ADOLC_threadNumber
```

However I could not find what it means. Does it make a link between two variables? Also ADOLC_threadNumber has not been declared before...

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor doesn't even know what a variable is. All that `#define` does is define a short(long?)hand for declaring a variable. I.e., if you type

```
ADOLC_OPENMP_THREAD_NUMBER;
```

It becomes

```
int ADOLC_threadNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now it seems obvious but it is the first time I see something similar. Hopefully I found a way to make it work! I will still send a message to the devs cause it is weird their package is not compiling directly

Answer (score 0):

It's just a text substitution. Everywhere in code where `ADOLC_OPENMP_THREAD_NUMBER` appears, it's substituted by `int ADOLC_threadNumber`.

As far as I see it, the line with the define itself is not problematic, but maybe the subsequent appearance of `ADOLC_OPENMP_THREAD_NUMBER`. However, to check this, we need to know more about the context.

Answer (score 0):

**#define** is a directive used often in **.h** files,
it creates a macro, which is the association of an identifier or parameterized identifier with a token string. 
After the macro is defined, the compiler can substitute the token string for each occurrence of the identifier in the source file.

**#define** may be associated with **#ifndef** directive to avoid to delare the identifier more than once :

```
#ifndef ADOLC_OPENMP_THREAD_NUMBER
#define ADOLC_OPENMP_THREAD_NUMBER int ADOLC_threadNumber
#endif
```